# find webelement that contains unknown span text

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath

I have this html snippet here.

[image]

This is what I want to achieve, after a user input a value, use the input value to check which PagePostsSectionPaglet contains it, find the PagePostsSectionPaglet and find the `className("_5sem")` that is in the same PagePostsSectionPaglet

```
get a list of text from webelement

//compare a list of text in PagePostsSectionPaglet with unknown user input
if text in PagePostsSectionPaglet = input year 
{
    find PagePostsSectionPaglet that contains text that is same with input year
    go through same PagePostsSectionPaglet and find className="_5sem">  
    {
       find UFIPagerLink  //inside class="_5sem"
       find UFIPagerIcon  //inside class="_5sem"
    }
}
```

**Problem** how to findwebelements PagePostsSectionPagelet that consists user input "text" instead of specific value?

tried different ways but all have this **SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.**

```
List <WebElement> PagePostsSectionPagelet = elm.findElements(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'PagePostsSectionPagelet')]//contains('"+elm.getText()+"')"));

List <WebElement> PagePostsSectionPagelet = elm.findElements(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'PagePostsSectionPagelet')]//span[elm.getText()]"));
```

my codes

```
    //tried to print the list of texts in AllPagePostsSectionPagelet but only returns the first value
    List <WebElement> AllPagePostsSectionPagelet= dr.findElements(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'PagePostsSectionPagelet')]//span[@class='_5em9 lfloat _ohe _50f4 _50f7']"));

    for (WebElement elm : AllPagePostsSectionPagelet){  
        if(year.equals(elm.getText())){  //year is the user input value
            //get weblement that contains the text
            List <WebElement> PagePostsSectionPagelet = elm.findElements(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'PagePostsSectionPagelet')]//elm.getText()")); //this is the issue
            System.out.println(PagePostsSectionPagelet); 
            for (WebElement elment : PagePostsSectionPagelet){
                List<WebElement> comments = elment.findElements(By.className("_5sem")); //find web element 

                //iterate through the comments 
                for (WebElement comment : comments) {

                       //find web elements by their respective class name
                       List<WebElement> commentsbutton = comment.findElements(By.className("UFIPagerLink"));
                       List<WebElement> repliesbutton = comment.findElements(By.className("UFIPagerIcon")); 
                }  
            }     
        //return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I understood from your question (Please correct me if I'm wrong), you are trying to search for a specific `div` tag which satisfies 2 conditions:

1. has an `id="PagePostsSectionPagelet"`
2. and within that tag there should be a `span` tag which matches the value entered by the user (eg: 2014)

Now, within that `div` tag, you want to fetch another `div` tag with `class="_5sem"`.

If what I've explained matches with what you are trying to achieve, then the xpath given below should work for the HTML source you've provided above.

```
"//span[text()='2014']/ancestor::div[contains(@id, 'PagePostsSectionPagelet')]//div[@class='_5sem']"
```

The Java code which you've provided can be reduced to:

```
//year is the user input value
String xp = "//span[text()='" + year + "']/ancestor::div[contains(@id, 'PagePostsSectionPagelet')]//div[@class='_5sem']";

WebElement comment = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xp)); 
// Add code to fetch 'UFIPagerLink' and 'UFIPagerIcon'
// which should be inside the div tag with class="_5sem"
```

Comment: yes, you have understood my question correctly. however, there is a **NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:{"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='PagePostsSectionPaglet' and span[text()='2013']]/div[@id='_5sem']"}** when i entered a user input of 2013 via the use of scanner. @jason

Comment: even if i changed your codes to `/div[@class='_5sem']`, it still have the same **NoSuchElementException** error @jason

Comment: @dark_space - Can you share the HTML code or link? Use gist.github.com to share source.

Comment: @dark_space - or just send me contents of `<div id='PagePostsSectionPaglet'>`.

Comment: here's the html code and link https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2cac47e720367abd2a18

Comment: i tried using this instead and it works `String xp = "//span[text()='" + year + "']//following::div[@class='_5sem']";` but it will carry on searching for 'UFIPagerLink' and 'UFIPagerIcon' that are in the next div. eg. if user input is 2014, it continues searching in 2013. how do i make it search in only that particular div? @jason

Comment: @dark_space - Sorry for my late response. But I was making a silly spelling mistake which made me confused as why my xpath wasn't working. I was copying the id (`PagePostsSectionPaglet` ) from your question which was spelled wrong. (Notice the word `Pagelet` in the id).

Comment: @dark_space - Anyways, I've updated the xpath. I'm sure this will work for you.

Comment: thanks for the effort, but the xpath doesnt seem to work as well as the 'UFIPagerLink' and 'UFIPagerIcon' inside the div tag with class="_5sem" cannot be fetched @jason

Comment: @dark_space - The xpath seems to be working fine. Try testing it in the browser console using `$x(" ...xpath... ")`. Also, I tried searching in the source of the HTML for `UFIPagerLink` or `UFIPagerIcon` but couldn't find it. Basically, I couldn't find the HTML snippet which you had sent in the gist.

Comment: i have included the html snippet for UFIPagerLink in the gist, its at line 39 and yes, the xpath seems to working fine when i tested it in the brower console. @jason

Comment: @dark_space - I meant that I couldn't find the snippet in the source code of the link.